# Numpy 2D array in Python 3.4

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have this code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("test.csv", sep=",")
```

data array looks like that:

[image]

The problem is that I can't split it by columns, like that:

```
week     = data[:,1]
```

It should split the second column into the week, but it doesn't do it:

*TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
*

How should I do this to make it work?

I also wondering, that what this code do exactly? (Don't really understand np.newaxis part)

```
week     = data['1'][:, np.newaxis]
```

Result: [image]

Comment: re: `np.newaxis`: print the `.shape` attribute of `data['1']` and `data['1'][:, np.newaxis]`

Comment: Here is the .csv file: http://www.filedropper.com/test_82

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues here.

First, `read_csv` uses a comma as a separator by default, so you don't need to specify that.

Second, the pandas `csv` reader by default uses the first row to get column headings.  That doesn't appear to be what you want, so you need to use the `header=None` argument.

Third, it looks like your first column is the row number.  You can use `index_col=0` to use that column as the index.

Fourth, for pandas, the first index is the column, not the row.  Further, using the standard `data[ind]` notation is indexing by column name, rather than column number.  And you can't use a comma to index both row and column at the same time (you need to use `data.loc[row, col]` to do that).

So for your case, all you need to do to get the second columns is `data[2]`, or if you use the first column as the row number then the second column becomes the first column, so you would do `data[1]`.  This returns a pandas `Series`, which is the `1D` equivalent of a `2D` `DataFrame`.

So the whole thing should look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=None, index_col=0)
week = data[1]
```

`data` looks like this:

```
    1   2     3   4
0                    
1    10   2   100  12
2    15   5   150  15
3    25   7   240  20
4    22  12   350  20
5    51  13   552  20
6   134  20   880  36
7   150  22   900  38
8   200  29  1020  44
9   212  31  1100  46
10  199  23  1089  45
11  220  32  1145  60
```

The '0' row doesn't exist, it is just there for informational purposes.

`week` looks like this:

```
0
1      10
2      15
3      25
4      22
5      51
6     134
7     150
8     200
9     212
10    199
11    220
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

However, you can give columns (and rows) meaningful names in pandas, and then access them by those names.  I don't know the column names, so I just made some up:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=None, index_col=0, names=['week', 'spam', 'eggs', 'grail'])
week = data['week']
```

In this case, `data` looks like this:

```
    week  spam  eggs  grail
1     10     2   100     12
2     15     5   150     15
3     25     7   240     20
4     33    12   350     20
5     51    13   552     20
6    134    20   880     36
7    150    22   900     38
8    200    29  1020     44
9    212    31  1100     46
10   199    23  1089     45
11   220    32  1145     50
```

And `week` looks like this:

```
1      10
2      15
3      25
4      33
5      51
6     134
7     150
8     200
9     212
10    199
11    220
Name: week, dtype: int64
```

For `np.newaxis`, what that does is add one dimension to the array.  So say you have a `1D` array (a vector), using `np.newaxis` on it would turn it into a `2D` array.  It would turn a `2D` array into a `3D` array, `3D` into `4D`, and so on.  Depending on where you put it (such as `[:,np.newaxis]` vs. `[np.newaxis,:]`, you can determine which dimension to add.  So `np.arange(10)[np.newaxis,:]` (or just `np.arange(10)[np.newaxis]`) gives you a shape `(1,10)` `2D` array, while `np.arange(10)[:,np.newaxis]` gives you a shape `(10,1)` `2D` array.

In your case, what the line is doing is getting the column with the name `1`, which is a `1D` pandas `Series`, then adding a new dimension to it.  However, instead of turning it back into a `DataFrame`, it instead converts it into a `1D` numpy array, then adds one dimension to make it a `2D` numpy array.

This, however, is dangerous long-term.  There is no guarantee that this sort of silent conversion won't be changed at some point.  To change a pandas objects to a numpy one, you should use an explicit conversion with the `values` method, so in your cases `data.values` or `data['1'].values`.

However, you don't really need a numpy array.  A `series` is fine.  If you really want a `2D` object, you can convert a `Series` into a `DataFrame` by using something like `data['1'].to_frame()`.